# Little problem calculating hazard function

Tags: survival, density-function, hazard, function

I'm starting to study maths again after a long time without having touch them and I'm currently with survival analysis.

I want to get a hazard function h(x), and I know that it can be calculated as the ratio of the density function f(x):

\begin{cases}
    0 & \text x <  0\\
    2x/(1+x^2 )^2              & \text{x ≥ 0}
\end{cases}

and the survival function S(x):

\begin{cases}
    1 & \text x <  0\\
    1/1+x^2              & \text{x ≥ 0}
\end{cases}

Sorry if it is a naive question, but how can I divide f(x)/S(x) to get h(x)? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hazard functions are usually defined only for $x>0$. So, can you simplify 
$\displaystyle h(x) = \dfrac{\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}}{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}??$

Comment: I was thinking about it, as simple as that, but don´t know if it is mathematically correct.

Comment: @Voronin_10 _What_ is mathematically  correct? The end result of the division which is a rational function (ratio of polynomials)? What you get is a valid hazard functionm in that the area under the curve is infinite(as it must be for all hazard functions) though a somewhat unusual one in that $h(x)$ decays away to $0$ as $x\to\infty$, that is, the hazard _decreases_ as age increases whereas in real life, hazards increase with age.